# C# Drag/Drop from a remote system

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a remote file viewer and want to be able to drag remote files and drop them into Windows Explorer.  I have a chicken-egg problem.  I can download the files to temp files.  I can create the data object pointing to the tmp files, but I don't want to trigger the actual download until they release the button over Explorer.

I tried looking at the MouseUp event, but it isn't triggered from my app.  It is triggered from Explorer.  I suppose I could write a Hook DLL to catch the mouse up event and just replace the empty file in the background with the download contents.  That seems a bit extravagant though.

Ideas?

Comment: This reminded me of a post by Raymond Chen. This might be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/07/2453927.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native solution, but you can check out [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23139/Transferring-Virtual-Files-to-Windows-Explorer-in) which details how it can be done. Good Luck!

Comment: The solution I used was found here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx  It's virtually the same as this article.  Thanks.